# Django combine selections

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following Models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() 

class User(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    user_name = models.TextField() 


def match_person(user_list):
    results = []
    for user in user_list:
       user_match = user_name.objects.select_related('person').
                    filter(alias=user).all()
       ....
       results.append(user_match)
return results
```

A Person can have one or more user names as well as their own name.
My match method basically iterates through a list of given user names  and stores the user and related person in a result.

Since my method only contains SELECT query, I wonder if I can combine my selections into one single query for better performance?

Answer (score 0):

A `values_list` will return a list of tuples with the values you want:

```
user_list = ['username1', 'username2', 'username3']
User.objects.filter(user_name__in=user_list).values_list('user_name','person__name')
```

will return

```
[('username1', 'person1'), ('username2', 'person1') ...]
```

PS. A `CharField` is better than a `TextField` for short strings such as names.